# ecryptfs-utils has no installation candidate on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ecryptfs

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and I am having issues to install the `ecrypt-utils` app. See the output below:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install  ecryptfs-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ecryptfs-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ecryptfs-utils' has no installation candidate
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, as the OP needs to know how to find out where the package is, before OP can think about adding a repo.

Comment: @ejjl there are a lot of similar question exactly like this one which only the name of package is different in them. That's a canonical answer to these kind of questions.

Comment: @Ravexina Agreed. My point, however, is: either 1) explain why 'Universe' is the answer to the question, or 2) point to a canonical answer that guides someone through the process of finding out why there is this error message, where to find out where the package can be found, and then how to install it. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: @ejjl (2): done.

Answer (score 7):

### Answer

The package [`ecryptfs-utils`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ecryptfs-utils) is available in the `universe` repository.

To enable the universe repo, do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ecryptfs-utils
```

### Further explanation:

#### Looking up packages

You can look up packages at https://packages.ubuntu.com/ Make sure you select the correct distribution (in your case Bionic, which corresponds to 18.04).

When you search for `ecryptfs-utils` you get the following:

> Package ecryptfs-utils
>
> ```
> [bionic (18.04LTS)][1] (misc): ecryptfs cryptographic filesystem (utilities) [universe]
> 111-0ubuntu5: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
> ```

As you can see, the package is available for 18.04 in the `universe` repository. You enable `universe` via the above-mentioned steps.

#### Repositories

A repository (oftentimes abbreviated to repo) is the name Ubuntu gives to an archive where software is stored. Ubuntu uses four main repositories:

1. Main
2. Universe
3. Restricted
4. Multivers

The `universe` repository contains "Community-maintained free and open-source software". For more info, see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu